# Как правильно и безопасно передавать информацию с клиента на сервер?

Tags: безопасность, веб-сервер, веб-программирование

Есть задача в самом простом объяснении. Есть список постов, у каждого отображается: кто написал пост, и текст. К примеру, я захотел удалить свой пост, который опубликовал раньше. Жму на кнопочку "Удалить". Вот здесь и встает вопрос, как это сделать правильно. У меня приходит одно решение, но оно, по мне, открывает большую брешь в безопасности сайта: хранить в посте, в каком-нибудь скрытом поле (в html-разметке), id этого поста, после чего передавать его на сервер, где в БД найдется запись с соответствующим id, после чего удалить этот пост из БД. Но что, если пользователь в html-разметке поменяет этот id так, что удалится совсем другой пост? Как это правильно сделать? И вообще, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие источники (книги, статьи) вы применяли, чтобы научиться создавать безопасные сайты? Спасибо.
**P.S. Думаю, языки и фреймворки в данном случае не важны, ведь безопасность - она одна, просто разные способы реализации.**

Comment: удалять то можно, наверное, только свои посты. так что, если даже подменит, то только на свой, а чужой вы ему не дадите удалить

Comment: _"если пользователь в html-разметке поменяет этот id так, что удалится совсем другой пост"_ -- в базе данных у каждого поста должен быть автор. при удалении проверяете: кто из авторов прислал запрос на удаление и кто автор у поста. если автор один и тот же, то помечаете пост как удаленный. реально удалять будете позже (например раз в день/неделю).

Comment: @Stack Спасибо! А где можно почитать об безопасности, абстрагируясь от деталей реализации?

Comment: @UraOs _"А где можно почитать об безопасности"_ -- например [тут](https://www.google.ru/webhp?q=site%3Ahabrahabr.ru%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1)